# i want to update the data type of fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I want to update the data type of fields I already created an index with data also visualization now  want to update the data type of one field. I am doing this in the console of dev tools

I tried to do it but giving an error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjY2T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're hitting the `_mapping` endpoint, you need to remove the `mappings` section in the payload and only have `properties`.

However, once a field is created you cannot change its type, you need to recreate a new index with the proper mapping field type.

**UPDATE:** If you need to set default values for your fields you can use the [`null_value`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html) mapping parameter.

Comment: should i keep put or any thing else in start of

Comment: I have created visualization and dashboards so it is a little difficult for me to recreate index again

Comment: There's no other way, you have to. But your visualizations will still work after recreating the index, because they are based on a data view not on the index itself. Just delete it the index and recreate it with the right mapping, then refresh your visualizations and it will work out

Comment: thankyou also i  have one more question then i f i need to set a default value of any fileds what should i use